# Showing that the sample variance for an SRS is a biased estimator of the population variance?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

EDIT: I suspect I may be going about this all wrong, so maybe disregard this.

So, I can get this far on my own: $E(\hat{\sigma}^2) = E(\frac{1}{n - 1}\sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2) = \frac{1}{n - 1}[E(\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i^2) - 2n\mu E(\bar{X}) + n\mu^2] = \frac{1}{n - 1}[E(\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i^2) - n\mu^2]$.

I know that $E(\bar{X}) = \mu$ and I'm given a formula for the variance of $\bar{X}$, so I suspect I'm somehow supposed to get from $E(\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i^2)$ to $E(\bar{X}^2)$, but I don't see how. I also have a formula for the covariance between each $X_i$ and $X_j$, though I don't see how I would use that. I don't know the distribution of the population I'm drawing from, so I can't evaluate $E(X_i^2)$, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check your definition of the sample variance. Are you sure it involves the (possibly unknown) parameter $\mu$?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't. I get how to fix that second part now, which is where the formulas come in, though I still don't understand how to calculate $E(\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i^2)$, which is mostly what's stumping me.

Comment: Okay, yeah, realized that $E(X_i^2)$ is just $E(X_i)^2 + Var(X_i)$, which I somehow convinced myself wasn't the cast. Sorry about this one.

Comment: Is there still a question then?